# MS Access 2016 query to insert column and group data by three criteria

Tags: ms-access, sql-insert

In MS Access I have this query to export data to Excel.

```
SELECT tblhrsmq_op_task_plot.ddate, tblhrsmq_op_task_plot.plot_id, tbltask_id.hrmqtask_name, ([hr_end]-[hr_begin])*24 AS qty
FROM tbltask_id INNER JOIN tblhrsmq_op_task_plot ON tbltask_id.hmtask_id = tblhrsmq_op_task_plot.hmtask_id
WHERE (((tblhrsmq_op_task_plot.plot_id)=[Formularios]![frm_export]![txtplot]));
```

The query return data like this

```
ddate   plot_id hrmqtask_name   qty
20/06/2018  54  task06  2,00
20/06/2018  54  task06  1,25
21/06/2018  54  task06  2,25
21/06/2018  54  task06  0,75
23/06/2018  54  task06  3,25
23/06/2018  54  task06  1,00
25/05/2018  54  task15  2,75
25/05/2018  54  task15  3,25
```

I need the query to insert a column(ddate2) next to column1 and group the data by ddate1, ddate2 and hrmqtask_name like this:

```
ddate1      ddate2      plot_id hrmqtask_name   qty
20/06/2018  23/06/2018  54  task06      10,50
25/05/2018  25/05/2018  54  task15      6,00
```

How do I program in SQL to get this result set?

Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following - you can use min() and max() to aggregate the dates and sum for the qty

```
SELECT 
  min(tblhrsmq_op_task_plot.ddate) as ddate1, 
  max(tblhrsmq_op_task_plot.ddate) as ddate2, 
  tblhrsmq_op_task_plot.plot_id, 
  tbltask_id.hrmqtask_name, 
  sum(([hr_end]-[hr_begin])*24) AS qty
FROM tbltask_id INNER JOIN tblhrsmq_op_task_plot ON tbltask_id.hmtask_id = tblhrsmq_op_task_plot.hmtask_id
WHERE (((tblhrsmq_op_task_plot.plot_id)=[Formularios]![frm_export]![txtplot]))
group by tblhrsmq_op_task_plot.plot_id,tbltask_id.hrmqtask_name,
;
```

Comment: Ian Kenney. 
Your SQL code works great for my project. As you know I did little changes.
This is my first time learning the use of Min and Max Functions.

I really appreciate your help.